Shortcut for replase Similar name in all tag
hello  I have a beginner's question.
<p>Usa is good</p>
<p>Usa is very nice</p>
<p>Usa is dismal</p>
<p>Usa is perfect</p>

When in editor select Usa in first p tag with mouse, all under Usa have underline and can select all usa world and change with new word . How can select all usa with keyboard? Pls say shortcut

Hi.  It looks like you are asking to have your homework done for you.  SO is here to help you learn, not do it for you.  Post some code of things you have tried and we can give you advice on how to improve it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Click before the U of Usa is good. Now your cursor is blinking before U.
Now use control + mouse click to Click before the U of Usa is very nice. Now your cursor is blinking before two U's.
Similarly control click before the third and fourth U. Now your cursor is blinking before all four U's.
Now, you when you type or select/replace, it will be done in all 4 places.
